# Communication between gsm modem and android device

Tags: android, gsm, at-command

I have a server running a C# server app. The app is supposed to periodically connect through a GSM modem to a set of devices(touchpads running android 2.2) and download some files.
It's the first time I come across GSM communication so I'm really lost. So far I'm guessing i need AT commands to communicate but I'm not sure how.

I'm guessing first step would be dialing ATD. When I get a response, how can i ask the device to send me data?
Do I need to code an app/service on the device that answers my calls? The data i need is stored into txt files on my SD card, but i can put it anywhere if it makes it easier.

It would be really nice if you could help me with some AT code that does similar things or anything that helps me understand how to make this work.

Thanks

Comment: Are these devices that you have control over? I.e, could you make modifications to the Android system itself? Without that, I don't see any way you could accomplish this. Android doesn't provide any way for an application to send or receive data over a phone call. If you are able to modify the android system running on these devices, it might be possible.

Comment: I guess not, all i can do is write applications. Do you have any other idea on how to accomplish what i need using this technology? Can I do the opposite and send data to my server instead of asking server to retrive it?

Comment: I don't know of any way you could do that using a normal phone call. However, you might look into using some sort of SIP service. It's not exactly my area of expertise, but I imagine you might be able to get more control over a SIP phone call on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an Internet server to mediate (or at least initiate) communication between the mobile-network devices.  This will need to have a server-type Internet Service Provider - ie, firewall that allows the desired incoming connection requests, an IP address that's static at least in the short term, a domain name pointed at it, etc.

At that point your server running the C# program has no need for a GSM modem of it's own (unless wired service is unavailable to its location).  If you do connect it via GSM, then you'll need yet another server with a server-type ISP to setup connections between it and the tablets, so you might as well just run your C# program on that machine.

Essentially, you will not directly deal with GSM at all - you'd just be writing applications to run on top of a somewhat limited IP network which doesn't permit connection requests to the clients.  The android stack on the tablets entirely conceals the process of interacting with the built-in GSM modem from the application developer - you just see a normal network sockets interface, in java or C.

If you want to do something with direct radio communication between a server and tablets in a small area, look at wifi or something like zigbee.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to use GPRS to send and receive data? Can I "wake" a device via GPRS to tell it to send data to server(so that the device is not connected to the internets all the time)?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you not deal with GSM, or GPRS, or Edge, or 3g, or LTE, or anything - because Android devices do not expose this to the application programmer, and mobile networks do not expose these clients to connection requests from the big bad Internet.  Instead, you are going to need a server reachable from the Internet to which all of the client tablets connect and wait for data - the detail of the radio scheme and modem command strings for doing that are entirely out of your control and hidden from you, you simply write normal sockets-style networking code in Java or C.

Comment: In the end I have addopted this approach. Centralized server running MQTT brocker and apache/php/mysql. I use MQTT to wake the device and php pages to move data(tho this could have been done also by tcp direct connection through sockets). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For this type of communication C2DM would be perfect for you. But you do need to write an app to respond to your request and upload the data to the server as well as writing a push message script for the server